# Search on SharedWithMe items using OneDrive API/SDK

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have a lot of shared Files and Folders from different users in OneDrive (Personal or Business). I want to perform search on the shared items. As we can search on the personal resource by below code/API call:

```
var response = await client.Me.Drive.Root.Search(searchText).Request().GetAsync();
```

Or

```
https://dev.onedrive.com/items/search.htm
```

How can we perform search on SharedWithMe items?

Answer (score 2):

Search is not supported by the `sharedWithMe` function. Only local items within the user's drive can be searched in this way.

I would suggest making a [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) request for this feature (these are actively tracked and a primary source for enhancements).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will post this as an idea.

Comment: Is it possible to search Shared items locally using this SDK call: await client.Drives[DriveId].Items[ItemId].Search(searchText).Request().GetAsync(); I am always getting empty result set in this call.

Comment: The SDK has the same limitations as the REST API. Under the covers it is basically a wrapper making calls to the REST APIs more native feeling.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually call search on the drive instead of the root of the drive and that will search local files, plus any other files that are shared with the user.

Comment: Since there are different endpoints to fetch the Personal and Shared With Me files. Users will like to perform search on them separately. It will be difficult to separate the consolidated result in our implementation.

Comment: The OneDrive web app doesn't have this capability either. It searches all the items in the local drive, and any other items shared with the user. At this point, there are no plans to add this capability.

Comment: Is it possible to search Shared items locally using this call: GET /drives/{Drive Id}/items/{Item Id}/search(q='{search text}'  I am always getting empty result set in this call?